# Add number in front of number in columns

Tags: python, string, numbers

I have this example columns

```
year_short
89
99
97
87
98
00
02
05
10
11
20
22
```

what I want to do is to make that column into like this

```
year_long
    1989
    1999
    1997
    1987
    1998
    2000
    2002
    2005
    2010
    2011
    2020
    2022
```

is it possible to make like that ?

Comment: `year_long = [1900 + i if i > 22 else 2000 + i for i in year_short]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the logic that any two digit year which is less than 25 belongs to the `2000` century, while any value greater than or equal to 25 belongs to the `1900` century:

```py
df["year_long"] = np.where(df["year_short"] < 25, 2000 + df["year_short"], 1900 + df["year_short"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, this is for Excel, should be similar in Numbers though, I will delete unless it may help others.

So perhaps:

```
=if(A2>22,1900+A2,2000+A2)
```

You may want greater than 23 or 30, depends on your data.

Comment: This looks to be Excel code, not Python.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen drat, sorry, just saw it and went for it.